# Why my navigation controller make transitions modally instead of push now?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue

Looking for help with some problem which i clearly don't understand since i'm just beginner here so please help me out if you can.

Here is my issue, so far i built all views through storyboard and all are showed by navigation controller using "push" segue set up in storyboard, till now everything worked as expected.

In some point i decided to add calendar view in the bottom half part of the main view controller to show up when user press the button. Following some advices found online i decided to add it as a child view controller (and did it programatically).

Here is the code i used to present the view:

```
addChild(calendarVC)
view.addSubview(calendarVC.view)
calendarVC.didMove(toParent: self)
```

and here is the code i used to dismiss the view:

```
willMove(toParent: nil)
removeFromParent()
```

Everything works great so far, but here is the catch:

after triggering removeFromParent() part, transition between every other view controller changed from push to modal. Almost like i lost connection with navigation controller somehow?
I don't know, and my knowledge level is way too low to figure it out myself, any attempts on finding answer here by searching similar topics also didn't give me any answer i can understand, so hoping someone can shed a light on my problem here.

Thanks

Comment: Where did you call this? `willMove(toParent: nil); removeFromParent()` ? This methods should be called on your child view contoller.

Comment: Oh my i'm quite embarrassed now, seems i didn't notice that i didn't call it on child view controller in dismissing part. You're totally right. After changing to calendarVC.willMove(toParent: nil) and calendarVC.removeFromParent() it works properly. I guess I learn something new every day. Thanks a lot. If you want to put it as an answer i'll be happy to mark it a correct one.

Comment: Sorry to contact you via a different question, but if you will reopen your other question (about collection view) I will prove to you that it _does_ work even when animating is true. That is why I was asking you for more information; there must be a mistake somewhere along the line, that _you_ are making, because a change in appearance while animating is perfectly possible. I have worked on this example all morning so I would appreciate it if you would not delete the question just as I'm about to answer it.

Comment: hey @matt, thanks for reply, i reopened it again. I totally agree that it might be my mistake somewhere, but it can't be from core data because we can read sqlite file. Like i said in my edit there, what i found with print statements is that method responsible for selecting cell style is called when animated is true and is not called when animated is set to false. Might be totally my mistake by putting that method in custom cell class but i just suspect that apply snapshot method has slightly different code depended on parameter, which in my case actually does a difference.

Comment: You didn't reopen it, it is deleted. I can't respond to a deleted question. :(

Comment: @matt Oh my bad, i did something wrong, please check again, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you invoke `willMove(toParent: nil) removeFromParent()` from child view controller.

Invoking the above functions from a parent view will remove the controller from the Navigation hierarchy.